# Add foreign key constraints in Laravel migration

Tags: php, laravel, artisan-migrate

I know a lot of people asked the same question many times but it seems as if I am not able to make the same solutions work for me.

I am not able to set foreign key for the related tables for which the `up()` has been given below:

```
//Migrate 1 Starts
public function up()
{
    Schema::create("UserTable", function($table){
        $table->tinyInteger("ApplicationID");
        $table->bigInteger("UserID");
        $table->string("UserName")->unique();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
//Migrate 1 Ends

//Migrate 2 Starts
public function up()
{
    Schema::create("Membership", function($table){
        $table->tinyInteger("ApplicationID");
        $table->bigInteger("UserID");
        $table->string("Password");
    }
}
//Migrate 2 Ends

//Migrate 3 Starts: This has the latest timestamp, so it runs after all tables are created
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('UserTable', function($table) {
        $table->primary("UserID");
        $table->foreign("UserID")->references("UserID")->on("Membership");
    });

    Schema::table('Membership', function($table) {
        $table->primary("UserID");
        $table->foreign("UserID")->references("UserID")->on("UserTable");
    });
}
//Migrate 3 Ends
```

The error I am getting is `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General rror: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table 'Membership' add constraint membership_userid_foreign foreign key ('UserID') references 'UserTable' ('UserID'))`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was setting up primary key at the time of setting up foreign key. This was causing problem.

So setting up of primary columns must be done while creating the tables, while foreign keys must be added once all the related tables have been created.

I guess its better that we create a `create_associations` migration file after all the tables have been created so that this migration has the latest timestamp, and by the time this file is executed, all the tables are present in the database.

Comment: Or any column that you want to make as foreign key, must be index and unsigned. So, try that as well.